# Printing Problem In 64-bit Crystal Reports for VS 2005

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm aware that this question may have been asked before, but I still haven't found any solution.

We're developing a smart client application with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2005. The application has been deployed to 32 bit machines and it runs well. However when we deployed to 64 bit machine, we found that the print button of Crystal Reports viewer didn't work. Note that we have installed CRRedist2005_X64.msi in that pc. 
We want to keep this source code in Visual Studio 2005.

Do you know any solution for this problem? Your suggestion will be appreciated.

Regards,

Anton

Comment: Have you tried the 32-bit version of Crystal Reports together with a 32-bit version of your app on 64-bit Windows?

Comment: yes, we have. The reports won't run at all, so we install 64-bit Crystal Reports runtime

Comment: The Platform Target option in build options is specifically set to x86 and not AnyCPU?

Comment: We use AnyCPU. We're trying your suggestion now.

Comment: Sorry, man, I'm all out of ideas. :(

Comment: Finally my friend solved it by compiling with Visual Studio 2005 installed on 64 bit OS and Crystal Reports for VS 2005 SP1 (https://smpdl.sap-ag.de/~sapidp/012002523100006007872008E/crvs05sp1.exe).

Comment: Glad to hear that. :) Perhaps you should post that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally my colleague solved it by compiling with Visual Studio 2005 installed on 64 bit OS and Crystal Reports for VS 2005 SP1. 
source: http://forums.sdn.sap.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1939320&tstart=0

Comment: can you help me out in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300956/crystal-report-is-not-opening-for-64-bit-machines or share the deployment steps for x64.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to set UseEXDialog=True 
Try this:

```
 Using frm As New System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog 
    frm.Document = mPrintDocument 
    frm.UseEXDialog=True  ' TRY THIS
```

It show a different type of printdialog, but it works on 64 bit OS

I've found this solution here:

http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/printdialog-not-displaying-64-bit-172427.aspx