# Crystal Reports Error When Installing Application On Another Computer

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I installed my widows form application to another computer everything work but lodging report gives error. I am using crystal reports

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to install crystal reports runtime. http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/crnetruntime/clickonce/CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_21.msi

Comment: I installed crystal report runtime but it gives this error also.

Comment: Identity, what arch of runtime did you install in your installation.

Comment: Please see this OP, i think this is the answer of your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300956/crystal-report-is-not-opening-for-64-bit-machines

Comment: I will try 32 bit crystal report runtime

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
32 bit crystal report runtime is the solution.
```